# Why does it prompt me twice in a row?

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, java.util.scanner, prompt

This while loop that is suppose to prompt for a price and a y/n and end if price = 0. However, when I run the code, it asks for the price, takes it, goes to a blank line, and I have to enter the number again before asking me the next question. For the second question, I only have to enter the input once.

And when I print the price array, the value is the number I inputted the second time.

```
    int keepGoing = 1;
    while (keepGoing > 0) {

        System.out.print("How much is the item? (If no more items, enter '0') ");
        if (in.nextDouble() > 0) {
            prices.add(in.nextDouble());

            System.out.print("Is the item a pet? (Y or N) ");
            String input = in.next();
            if (new String("Y").equals(input) || new String("y").equals(input)) {
                isPet.add(true);
            }
            else { isPet.add(false); }
        }
        else { keepGoing = 0; }
    }
```

Help please?

Answer (score 3):

That's because each time you write `in.nextDouble()`, the user will be need to type something into the scanner. Instead, you should store the input in a tempory variable:

```
    Double input = in.nextDouble(); // Keep the input in this variable
    if (input > 0) {                // You can use it on each of these lines
        prices.add(input);          // so that the user doesn't have to type it twice.

        System.out.print("Is the item a pet? (Y or N) ");
        String input = in.next();
        if (new String("Y").equals(input) || new String("y").equals(input)) {
            isPet.add(true);
        }
        else { isPet.add(false); }
    }
    else { keepGoing = 0; }
```

*A little side note: keepGoing should probably be a `boolean` instead of an `int`*

*Also, you can use `new String("Y").equalsIgnoreCase(input)` so that you don't need the `||`*

Answer (score 1):

It asks you twice because you call the `in.nextDouble()` method twice, one in the `if` statement and another time in the following line.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the comments on your code below:

```
int keepGoing = 1;
while (keepGoing > 0) {

    System.out.print("How much is the item? (If no more items, enter '0') ");
    if (in.nextDouble() > 0) { // <-- You are asking for the input here 
        prices.add(in.nextDouble()); // <-- and asking for the input here again.

        System.out.print("Is the item a pet? (Y or N) ");
        String input = in.next();
        if (new String("Y").equals(input) || new String("y").equals(input)) {
            isPet.add(true);
        }
        else { isPet.add(false); }
    }
    else { keepGoing = 0; }
}
```

Just change your code to be like this:

```
int keepGoing = 1;
double d = 0;
while (keepGoing > 0) {

    System.out.print("How much is the item? (If no more items, enter '0') ");

    d = in.nextDouble();

    if (d > 0) {

        prices.add(d);

        System.out.print("Is the item a pet? (Y or N) ");
        String input = in.next();
        if (new String("Y").equals(input) || new String("y").equals(input)) {
            isPet.add(true);
        }
        else { isPet.add(false); }
    }
    else { keepGoing = 0; }
}
```